# Getting a error where my output is starting with a - symbol

Tags: assembly, null, arm

This is my assembly code that wrote it runs perfectly however I need to fix some things that a school compiler is giving me this error message.

> A diff was done between the output of your program and the output of
>   the solution. Your program's output is preceded by a - symbol and is
>   highlighted in red. The solution's output is preceded by a + symbol
>   and is highlighted in green. Lines output by both your program and the
>   solution are not colored and do not have a symbol preceding the line.
>   We have attempted to darken the differences between your output and
>   the solution's, please update your source code to fix any problems. If
>   you see {NULL} it means that you are trying to output the NULL
>   character.
>
> ```
> @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@  ENTER two numbers (i.e '0'....'9')
> - r0 x3003 intro     r1 x7fff 32767     r2 x0000 0         r3 x0000 0         
> - r4 x0000 0         r5 x0000 0         r6 x0000 0         r7 x3003 intro     
> -  cc(+) Now at x3002: halt
> +8
> +4
> +8 - 4 = 4
> ```

```
.ORIG x3000     

        LEA R0, intro ; Load the address of intro string
        PUTS    ; Invokes BIOS routine to output string


        GETC     
        OUT      
        AND R1,R1,#0   
        ADD R1,R1,R0   
        LEA R0, NEWLINE  
        PUTS     
        GETC     
        OUT      
        AND R2,R2,#0   
        ADD R2,R2,R0   
        LEA R0, NEWLINE  
        PUTS     

        AND R3,R3,#0   
        ADD R3,R3,#15
        ADD R3,R3,#15
        AND R4,R4,#0
        ADD R4,R3,#2   
        ADD R3,R3,#15
        ADD R3,R3,#3   

        AND R5,R5,#0   
        ADD R5,R5,R3   

        NOT R3,R3
        ADD R3,R3,#1   


        ADD R1,R1,R3   
        ADD R2,R2,R3   
        AND R6,R6,#0   
        ADD R0,R1,R6
        ADD R0,R0,R5   
        OUT      

        AND R6,R6,#0  
        ADD R0,R4,R6  
        OUT      

        ADD R3,R4,#13
        AND R6,R6,#0  
        ADD R0,R3,R6   
        OUT

        AND R6,R6,#0
        ADD R0,R4,R6  
        OUT      

        AND R6,R6,#0
        ADD R0,R2,R6  
        ADD R0,R0,R5   
        OUT      

        AND R6,R6,#0
        ADD R0,R4,R6  
        OUT      
        ADD R3,R3,#15
        ADD R3,R3,#1     
        AND R6,R6,#0
        ADD R0,R3,R6  
        OUT      
        AND R6,R6,#0
        ADD R0,R4,R6  
        OUT      

        NOT R2,R2
        ADD R2,R2,#1   
        ADD R6,R1,R2   

        BRn neg      
        BR pos       

        neg Not R6,R6    
            ADD R6,R6,#1
            AND R3,R3,#0
            ADD R3,R4,#13
            AND R4,R4,#0  
            ADD R0,R3,R4  
            OUT

        pos ADD R6,R6,R5   
            AND R4,R4,#0   
            ADD R0,R6,R4   
            OUT      

            LEA R0, NEWLINE  
            PUTS     
            HALT    




        intro .STRINGZ   "ENTER two numbers (i.e '0'....'9')\n"
        NEWLINE .STRINGZ "\n"   ; String that holds the newline character

        .END
```

Comment: That's not from the compiler/assembler, that's from a script that runs your program and does a `diff -u` or something similar of the output against the required output.  What is this program supposed to do?  What did you find when you ran it under a debugger?  This isn't a [mcve] with this big block of uncommented code.  It looks like your code has some kind of register dump, instead of printing just numbers.

Comment: Well the program works and its doing what it should be doing im just not sure why Im getting a differences error not even sure what difference error is tbh never had one before

Comment: The output shows that intro is at 3003 and halt is at 3002. I think you have submitted an earlier version of your code that only has three instructions.

Comment: Are you sure this is ARM assembly?  It really doesn't look like that.